# Pattern match Jackson JSON in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, jackson

I am wondering if it is possible to do pattern matching on [Jackson JSON objects](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) in Scala. We are currently using [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) in a Project heavily and would benefit from being able to do pattern matching of Json ObjectNode/JsonNode objects.

If this is not possible, how would I go about adding this functionality? I was thinking something in terms of implicit conversion from JsonNode/ObjectNode to `MyClass`, where MyClass would have `unapply` method, doing JsonNode.toString and regex matching. If my logic is correct, I could then do pattern matching on JsonNode objects. Of course, there could be better ways I am not aware of, or this one may not work for reasons I am not yet aware of. To illustrate my case, I would like to be able to perform something in terms of:

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

val json = mapper.createObjectNode()
                .put("key1","value1")
                .put("key2","value2")
                .put("key3","value3")

json match {
  case MyClass("key1", "value1", "key2", y) => println("Found key1 with value1, where key2 is " + y)
  case MyClass("key1", x) => println("Key1 value is " + x)
  ...
  _ => println("No match found")
}
```

Comment: In addition to asking here, you may want to ask on Jackson mailing list (there is no separate one yet for Scala module, just regular 'user@jackson.codehaus.org').

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I also posted the question to Jackson mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to make use of the case class deserialization? 
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/deser/CaseClassDeserializerTest.scala

If that doesn't work, I think you would be better off creating extractors to represent your domain objects. Code below assumes a scala Map, but it should give you an idea. No implicit conversion required.

```
case class DomainObjectA(v1: String, v2: String)
object DomainObjectAExtractor {
  def unapply(m: Map[String, String]) = for {
     v1 <- m.get("key1")
     v2 <- m.get("key2")
  } yield DomainObjectA(v1, v2)
}

case class DomainObjectB(v3, v4, v5)
object DomainObjectBExtractor {
  def unapply(m: Map[String, String]) = for {
     v3 <- m.get("key3")
     v4 <- m.get("key4")
     v5 <- m.get("key5")
  } yield DomainObjectB(v3, v4, v5)
}

json match {
  case DomainObjectAExtractor(a@DomainObjectA(_, _)) => a
  case DomainObjectBExtractor(b@DomainObjectB(_, _, _)) => b
}
```

However, if you insist on trying to match against the key/value pairs, there may be ways to accomplish something which is acceptable for you. It is not possible to pass input into the unapply function from the `case`, which I think would be required if I understand what you want to do correctly. It may be possible to do this with macros which are experimental in the soon-to-be-officially-released scala 2.10. I haven't played with them enough to know if this is or is not possible though.

If ordering of keys was assumed, you could come up with a `::` unapply operator similar to `::` for list. This could extract the `K, V` pairs in this known order. Personally, this is too fragile for my tastes.

```
val json = Map(("key1" -> "one"), ("key2" -> "two"))

object -> {
  def unapply[A, B](ab: (A, B)) = Some(ab)
}

object :: {
  def unapply[K, V](m: Map[K, V]): Option[((K, V), Map[K, V])] = 
    m.headOption.map(_ -> m.tail)
}

scala> json match {
     |   case ("key1" -> "one") :: ("key2" -> value2) :: _ => value2
     | }
res0: java.lang.String = two
```

You would not be able to extract keys in the wrong order though

```
scala> json match {
     |   case ("key2" -> value2) :: _ => value2
     |   case _ => "match fail"
     | }
res2: java.lang.String = match fail
```

You could write `Key1`, `Key2`, `Key3` as well. This may or may not scale well.

```
object && {
  def unapply[A](a: A) = Some((a, a))
}

object Key2 {
  def unapply[V](m: Map[String, V]) = m.get("key2")
}

object Key1 {
  def unapply[V](m: Map[String, V]) = m.get("key1")
}

scala> json match {
     |   case Key2(value2) && Key1(value1) => (value2, value1)
     | }
res5: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) = (two,one)
```

Comment: I am not sure how to go about using case class deserialization to achieve what I want. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: What exactly is `MyClass`? Does it represent a domain object/request or is it just some general extractor that you want to create. Can json jave any arbitrary set of keys which you are trying to extract? If so, the CaseClassDeserializerModule isn't going to help. Most people don't need to do this though as they are trying to deserialize a json string with some known set of keys. If this is the case, the keys don't need to be part of the extraction. You could create case classes to represent each of the possible types you could be deserializing to.

Comment: The best solution would be for MyClass to be general extractor. However, if that is not possible, also custom domain objects will suffice. However, I need to match the objects in runtime, as I have no prior knowledge of what will be in the json in compile time. Based on that, your first code example might be what I am looking for. However, if possible, I would like to know if it is possible to use solution with case class deserialization where I don't know which object it will need to serialize to. Something like your first example.

Comment: Not knowing enough, I would make sure you think long and hard about whether you really need something that general. From your example, it looks like you are expecting json to contain `"key1"`/`"value1"` and some `"key2"` with an uknown value `y`. How do you know to expect these keys? Does this represent some known type? What if `"key1"` contains a value besides `"value1"`? I don't think `CaseClassDeserializerModule` is going to help you here.